# Receive notification whenever anyone signs-in to my AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'd like to receive a notification whenever anyone signs-in to our production AWS account.  Ideally the notification will appear in a Slack channel.  My understanding is that I can use CloudTrail to monitor AWS API management events.  I can then use EventBridge to detect certain events and send these to an SNS topic, and from there onwards to Slack.

However, AWS have just informed me that I will need to setup a separate EventBridge rule in every single AWS region in order to do this.  Apparently the sign-in event could happen in **any** AWS region depending upon which region was last being used by the user in question.

How can I receive notifications of all sign-in events without having to setup EventBridge rules in every AWS region?

I'm doing this so I can be notified of access by my team.  It would also be great if anyone can suggest a way of receiving more granular info, such as when someone accesses a particular service (EC2, S3 etc)

Thanks.